# Using container managed authentication in Spring Boot and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

I have `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<role rolename="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
<user username="test" password="qwerty" roles="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

I want use it in my `Spring Boot` rest service. I created configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private String tomcatRoleName;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .jee()
                .j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter());
    }

    @Bean
    public J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        final J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter = new J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter();
        j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());

        final J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource = new J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource();
        j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.setMappableRolesRetriever(simpleMappableAttributesRetriever());

        final SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper = new SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper();
        simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper.setConvertAttributeToUpperCase(true);
        j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.setUserRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper(simpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper);

        j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationDetailsSource(j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource);
        return j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappableAttributesRetriever simpleMappableAttributesRetriever() {
        final SimpleMappableAttributesRetriever simpleMappableAttributesRetriever = new SimpleMappableAttributesRetriever();
        simpleMappableAttributesRetriever.setMappableAttributes(ImmutableSet.of("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        return simpleMappableAttributesRetriever;
    }
}
```

But, When I run this application and try to log in, I get an error:

```
2018-06-14 16:26:15.452 DEBUG 15633 --- [io-8080-exec-10] p.j.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter : Checking secure context token: null
2018-06-14 16:26:15.452 DEBUG 15633 --- [io-8080-exec-10] p.j.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter : PreAuthenticated J2EE principal: null
2018-06-14 16:26:15.452 DEBUG 15633 --- [io-8080-exec-10] p.j.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter : No pre-authenticated principal found in request
```

It seems that Spring does not see `Tomcat's` users. Any Idea how can I fix it?

Comment: were you able to use container managed security using Spring boot? I have a similar requirement and not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @PC84, No, I refused of that. The easiest way I could find is to parse `tomcat-users.xml` and create a spring security configuration based on it